# No Visual Studio save prompt on close

Tags: visual-studio-2010, save, prompt

Recently I've begun experiencing the following error in Visual Studio 2010:

Whenever I close my project or solution I receive no "Save Changes" prompt, it just automatically saves dirty files. However, I still receive the prompt when closing dirty items separately. Does anybody know which settings I might have bungled up?

Addition: I use no source control, and have just tried resetting all environment settings to default, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are **some utilities that allow you to do this for any application**. For example, see

[**Check This Link**](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#NoClose)

I got this from [**Here**](https://superuser.com/questions/155622/prompt-if-i-really-want-to-close-visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks for answering. It appears however that none of the solutions fixes my specific issue. To clarify, my issue is the lack of a "Save Yes/No" prompt that I can use to save or not save changes I've made, instead of everything automatically being saved on project close.

Comment: OK. Then you will have one final solution.That is uninstall vs 2010 completely and then install fresh copy.Will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: B'cos there is some software corruption in your vs 2010.May be some dll or like that.